# Error of using epsfig

Tags: diagrams

I having an error below

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}[h]{1.08\columnwidth}
\centering
 \centerline{\epsfig{figure/test123.eps,width=1\columnwidth}}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
```

---

Comment: no document written after 1993 should be using epsfig package just use `\includegraphics` also `minipage` has no `[h]` option.

Comment: if you _really_ want to use `\epsfig` (why?) then you are missing the `file=` key before the image name,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i uses `epsfig` because I can adjust the size.

Comment: no. epsfig package was written (by me) in 1993 as a legacy package _then_ to translate a syntax popular in the 1980s into the standard latex graphicx package syntax. There is absolutely no reason to use it this century.

Comment: your `\centering` and `\centerline` are doing nothing as your image is full width, just use `\begin{figure}[htp]\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{figure/test123}\end{figure}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because I am writing a conference paper, which have 2 column in a paper. and using `epsfig` having a large image compare to `includegraphic[scale=0.6]`

Comment: No. do not use epsfig, it simply a few lnes of code that converts \epsfig into the equivalent `\includegrapics` code. there is absolutely nothing that `\epsfig` can do that `\includegraphics` can not do, it is just a less convenient and slower syntax for the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

The actual error message is because you have the incorrect syntax for `\epsfig` the image name should be given as `file=figure/test123.eps` and you have omitted the `file=` key.

However `epsfig` was written just to help convert documents that were old at the time (1993) to standard latex there is no reason to use it now.

Also `minipage` does not have an `[h]` option (unknown options are silently ignored) but you don't need a minipage here anyway as the `figure` environment already acts as a containing box, so you just need:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{figure/test123}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The title of the post is "Error of using epsfig" so the OP already knew... ;-)